# How can I change the cesium lighting setup so the tiles appear the same zoomed in and out?

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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). However, a free key will be needed to make it work. The key can be obtained by going to https://www.maptiler.com/ to create a free account. Your key will then be on https://cloud.maptiler.com/account/keys/

The code is:

```
const osm = new Cesium.UrlTemplateImageryProvider({
   url : 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/ch-swisstopo-lbm-dark/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=<your  key>',
});

console.log( osm.url )

const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  baseLayer: Cesium.ImageryLayer.fromProviderAsync(osm),
  baseLayerPicker: false,
  geocoder: false,
  animation: false,
  timeline: false,
  infoBox: false,
  homeButton: true,
  fullscreenButton: false,
  sceneModePicker: false,
  selectionIndicator: false,
  navigationHelpButton: false,
  terrainProvider: null,
  creditContainer: document.createElement('none'),
});
```

The image this produces when zoomed out is:

[image: zoomed out globe]

There is a light blue tint to the globe. However, if I zoom in, I see:

[image: zoomed in globe]

which matches the tile set I am using (CH swisstopo LBM Dark).

I figure there is something about the lighting that needs to be changed so zoomed out will look the same as zoomed in, but I am not sure how to do that...? (I want the dark zoomed in look, not the light blue when zoomed out)

[UPDATE 1]
What has gotten me a bit closer is setting:

```
viewer.scene.globe.atmosphereLightIntensity = 0
```

which then results in the zoomed out image:

[image: no atmosphere lighting]

instead of a light blue, it is a light gray.

There is the bluish ring around the globe which needs to go away as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be to set:

```
viewer.scene.globe.showGroundAtmosphere = false;
viewer.scene.skyAtmosphere.show = false
```

this produces the zoomed out image of:

[image: without tint or ring]

And zooming in no longer shows a distinct color shift with the drawn tiles. There is no ring.

There is a useful demo which I had missed to play with the possible settings.

[Cesium Atmosphere Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Atmosphere.html)